# How To get the admin's email which has the role Administrator?

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, email

I want to send an email to my magento website admin from my custom module.
How To get the admin's email which has the role Administrator?

**Magento Version 1.9**

Comment: refer http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/122781/45103

Comment: Thanks, I need the administrator user role admins email,Not the transaction emails

Comment: any one can help me in this please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find Below Code

```
$rule = Mage::getModel('admin/rules')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('resource_id','all');

$rule->getSelect()
     ->reset(Zend_Db_Select::COLUMNS)
     ->columns('role_id')
     ->group(array('role_id'));
foreach ($rule as $role) {
    //echo $role->getRoleId();
    $users=Mage::getModel('admin/roles')->load($role->getRoleId())->getRoleUsers();
    $adminUsers = Mage::getModel('admin/user')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('user_id', array( 'in' => $users)); 
    foreach ($adminUsers as $adminUser) {
        $email=$adminUser->getEmail();
    }
}
```